# Reference TextBoxes in a Userform as if they were in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, userform

I have a UserForm in which I have placed several TextBoxes that are related to each other by each displaying data from an array of strings.  The TextBoxes are defined via the UserForm object editor as tbx1, tbx2 and tbx3.  The string array is defined as:

```
    Dim arText(3) As String
```

I wish to use array access to be able to specify an index as a Long and have it set the text in one of the TextBoxes to the text in the corresponding arText element.  To do this, I'm trying to set up an array of TextBox references to reference the TextBoxes in the UserForm:

```
    Dim arTBs (3) As TextBox

    Sub SetText(Index As Long)
        arTBs(Index).Value = arText(Index)
    End Sub
```

Of course, I have to initialize the array of TextBoxes with the references to the defined TextBoxes and I'm doing it this way:

```
    Sub InitTBs()
        Set arTBs(1) = tbx1
        Set arTBs(2) = tbx2
        Set arTBs(3) = tbx3
    End Sub
```

This seems simple enough, but when I run it, the project halts at

```
    Set arTBs(1) = tbx1
```

with a Type Mismatch error.  When I check my Locals window, I see that the controls have been initialized and are type TextBox/TextBox and the array elements are all Nothing of type TextBox.

The fact that they're not set to anything yet doesn't bother me, as that's what I'm trying to do in Sub InitTBs, but the different types does and I'm wondering if that's the problem causing the execution error, and if so, is there a way to implement my scheme that will allow the types to match up?

Comment: Then you have one of the types wrong - either the array or the textboxes. But you haven't shown us enough code to know which. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please, change the declaration `Dim arTBs (3) As TextBox` in `Dim arTBs (1 To 3) As MSForms.TextBox`. Firstly **the text boxes used on a Form are of the type I suggested above**. A text box object can be declared `As TextBox` only on a `Form` type  (on the sheet). These are of `ActiveX` type. And such a 1D array is in base 0, without `Option Base 1` on top of the module...

Comment: Besides that, of course if you do not use `Option Base 1`, you should also declare `arText(1 to 3) As Long` and take care to previously **load it**... As long, to avoid another error when try using `arTBs(Index).Value = arText(Index)`.

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru, using MSForms.TextBox was the ticket.

Comment: How do you put a Sub in a Sub?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim artbs(3) As Object

Sub InitTBs()

With Userform2 'the name of the Userform
Set artbs(0) = .tbx1
Set artbs(1) = .tbx2
Set artbs(2) = .tbx3
End With

arText = Array(45, 67, 89) ' only for example

For Index = 0 To 2
    artbs(Index).Value = arText(Index)
Next Index

UserForm2.Show
 
End Sub
```

Object type accept any object.

Have to define the userform name to refer to an object on it.

Comment: This code should be part of the code behind of the form (eg the Initialize-event), not in a module. There, you can use `Me` instead of  `Userform2`. Also, see the comment of FaneDuru: Use the right type `MSForms.TextBox` - use `Object` only if really necessary as the compiler cannot check for errors (and you don't have the help of intellisence)

Comment: Note that using the default instance of a form, although often done, is seen as bad habit. Better create an instance of the form by yourself.

Comment: @funt This is the correct way if you don't know the exact type of an object. tbx1 itself define its exact object as `Typename(tbx1)`

Comment: But you know the right type, don't you?

Comment: @funt i don't say bad habit only its my habit. In this way i'm sure that this is the same instance.

Comment: @funt if the OP knew wouldn't ask

Comment: It actually was inside the UserForm, in an Initialize Sub that's called from the UserForm_Initialize handler.  The real trick was using the MSForms.TextBox, the rest was working fine.

Comment: FunThomas, actually, I knew enough to know they weren't matched up and when I saw the MSForms it clicked right away.  Ran into this quite a few years ago and had forgotten all about it.  Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the type I used in declaring the TextBox array.  There is a difference between TextBoxes used in a UserForm, which is a kind of MSForm, and those used outside of a form.  Because the TextBoxes I was referencing were declared in the UserForm object, any reference to the TextBoxes, such as that in the array, must be to a MSForms.TextBox, rather than just a TextBox.  Changing the declaration of the TextBox array to

```
    Dim arTBs (1 To 3) As MSForms.TextBox
```

eliminated the problem.

I should also mention that I forgot to explain that all of the code I provided was inside the UserForm module, so the With statement and UserForm references some suggested were not necessary.